# Quickblox ios 1 on 1 chat

Tags: ios, chat, quickblox

1 to 1 chat works fine when both users are online. If the receiver goes offline, i send push notification, that works fine. But when the offline user comes back online he did not get the messages he received when he was offline. Help please.

Comment: You should implement chat history:
http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat/1:1_Chat_history

Answer (score 0):

The proper workflow for offline messages is:

1. User1 and User2 are online
2. User1 goes offline (app goes to background) - call Chat logout method
3. User2 sends some messages to User1
4. User1 goes online and receives these messages from User2

Comment: I'm following this workflow but still user1 do not recieve messages when he logs back in.